# Simple Binary Classification Using Theano Error

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, logistic-regression

I got an error when trying to create a simple binary classification for XOR case using Theano. It said dimension mismatch, but I can't find out what variable cause that.

and the strange part, my program is works when I change the number of neuron in the last layer. When I change to use 2 neuron in the last layer, and change that layer to softmax layer, and also use the negative log likelihood (multiclass classification style), this program is works fine.

This is my full code:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T 

class HiddenLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, input, nIn, nOut, is_last, W=None):
        self.input = input

        W_val = np.random.randn(nIn,nOut)*0.001
        b_val = np.zeros((nOut,))

        self.W = theano.shared(np.asarray(W_val,dtype=theano.config.floatX),
                               name='W',borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(np.asarray(b_val,dtype=theano.config.floatX),
                               name='b',borrow=True)

        self.z = T.dot(input,self.W) + self.b

        if(is_last==0):            
            self.output = T.switch(self.z < 0 , 0 ,self.z)
        else:
            self.output = T.nnet.sigmoid(self.z)
            self.y_pred = self.output > 0.5

        self.params = [self.W, self.b]

    def cost_function(self,y):
        return -T.mean(y*T.log(self.output)+(1-y)*T.log(1-self.output))

    def errors(self,y):
        return T.mean(T.neq(self.y_pred,y))

alfa = 1
epoch = 1000
neu = 5        

inpx = np.array([[1,0],[1,1],[0,0],[0,1]])
inpy = np.array([1,0,0,1])

x = T.fmatrix('x')
y = T.ivector('y')

layer0 = HiddenLayer(
    input = x,
    nIn = 2,
    nOut = neu,
    is_last=0
)

layer1 = HiddenLayer(
    input = layer0.output,
    nIn = neu,
    nOut = 1,
    is_last=1
)

params = layer0.params + layer1.params
cost = layer1.cost_function(y) 
grads = T.grad(cost, params)
updates = [(param_i, param_i - alfa * grad_i) for param_i, grad_i in zip(params, grads)]
eror = layer1.errors(y)

train_model = theano.function([x,y], [eror,cost],updates=updates,allow_input_downcast=True)

test_model = theano.function([x,y],[eror,layer1.y_pred],allow_input_downcast=True)

for i in xrange(epoch):
    etr,ctr = train_model(inpx, inpy)
    if i%(epoch/10)==0:
        print etr,ctr

et,pt = test_model(inpx,inpy)
print pt
```

and the error:

```
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 1, input[1].shape[1] = 4)
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{neq,no_inplace}(sigmoid.0, DimShuffle{x,0}.0)
Toposort index: 41
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(int32, row)]
Inputs shapes: [(4L, 1L), (1L, 4L)]
Inputs strides: [(4L, 4L), (16L, 4L)]
Inputs values: [array([[ 0.94264328],
       [ 0.99725735],
       [ 0.5       ],
       [ 0.95675617]], dtype=float32), array([[1, 0, 0, 1]])]
Outputs clients: [[Shape(Elemwise{neq,no_inplace}.0), Sum{acc_dtype=int64}(Elemwise{neq,no_inplace}.0)]]
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your y and inpy variables: what you are trying to do is to have y be the expected output of the network. Your network is given a dataset with 4 elements, each having 2 features, you thus have 4 rows in your input matrix, and 2 columns. You are thus expected to have 4 elements in your predicted output, that is 4 rows in your y or inpy matrix, but you are using a vector, which in theano is a row vector and thus has only one row. You need either to transpose your y vector when computing the cost, or to define your y variable as a matrix, and thus to have inpy as a (4,1) matrix instead of a (4,) vector (once again, vectors are row vectors in theano).

Hope this helps,

Best

Comment: yap, thanks for your answer, after trying several times I solved it by change the errors and cost code to something like this: `return T.mean(T.neq(T.reshape(self.y_pred,(4,)),y))`